# Cannot reconnect to crtmpserver

Tags: rtmp

I use crtmpserver 1.1 and streaming movie recording by IP camera.

Once network disconnect, IP camera cannot reconnect to the RTMP server and the following

warning is shown.

"basertmpappprotocolhandler.cpp:897 Stream name XXX already occupied and application doesn't allow
duplicated inbound network streams"

After restarting the server, I can reconnect to the server.

How to solve this problem without restarting the server and not rename the stream name?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the source code to solve this problem by flowing steps:

1. get the old IN RTMP stream
2. unlink the all OUT streams that subscribes the old IN RTMP stream
3. stop the old RTMP stream & unregister the old RTMP stream
4. create new IN RTMP stream base on the new request
5. bind the OUT streams to the new IN stream

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in crtmpserver. See this discussion on google groups

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/c-rtmp-server/o4dfEycNdRA